# "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable defined in an enclosing scope." after changing Execution Environment

Tags: java

I have a problem with my Java code in Eclipse. When I was developing my program, there was always a warning: "Build Path specifies execution environment JAVA SE 1.7...", and finding it odd, I searched for it here, and got to the conclusion that I had to remove *JRE System Library [JSE-1.3]*, and add a more recent one, which I did.

However, after applying the new libraries, all of my three under-development files instantly got lots of errors warnings. Not understanding what the actual problem was, I tried to return the old libraries to my project's properties. But after doing it, although around 90% of errors went away, there were still some left. Stating:

"Cannot refer to the non-final local variable defined in an enclosing scope." And it is wanting me to put **final** on every single variable that I use with the ActionListener or MouseListener. The new warning message is:

"Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.3. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment."

Here is the code, I am sorry if I did a mistake, but I am new to the programming language, and I can't find a solution for this. The code is simplified to a point it won't work with only that, showing only an example.

```
public class MainGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Physics Simulator");

            JButton exitButton = new JButton(" Exit ");
        exitButton.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        exitButton.setBounds(331, 15, 80, 24);
        exitButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        exitButton.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        exitButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        exitButton.setBackground(SystemColor.scrollbar);

            JCheckBox exitAskingcheck = new JCheckBox("Exit without asking");
        exitAskingcheck.setSelected(false);
        exitAskingcheck.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        exitAskingcheck.setBackground(SystemColor.scrollbar);
        exitAskingcheck.setBounds(775, 17, 133, 23);
        exitAskingcheck.setFocusPainted(false);

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

                if ( exitAskingcheck.isSelected() ) {
                System.exit(0); } else {

                    JFrame exitAsk = new JFrame("Physics Simulator");
                    exitAsk.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    exitAsk.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    exitAsk.setSize(400,200);

                    JButton no = new JButton("Not yet...");
                    no.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11));
                    no.setFocusPainted(false);
                    no.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                            exitAsk.setVisible(false);
                            exitAsk.removeAll();
                            exitAsk.setEnabled(false);

                        }
                    });

                    JButton yes = new JButton("Yes");
                    yes.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11));
                    yes.setFocusPainted(false);
                    yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });

                    JLabel askText = new JLabel("Are you sure you want to leave?");
                    askText.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    askText.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 15));
                    exitAsk.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
                    exitAsk.getContentPane().add(no);
                    exitAsk.getContentPane().add(yes);
                    exitAsk.getContentPane().add(askText);
                    no.setBounds(220,100,100,30);
                    yes.setBounds(40,100,100,30);
                    askText.setBounds(64,27,250,30);

                    exitAsk.setVisible(true);
                    exitAsk.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                    exitAsk.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    exitAsk.setResizable(false);

                }
            }
        });
```

The error message is given at the variable **exitAskingcheck** on:

```
if ( exitAskingcheck.isSelected() ) {
```

And also at each **exitAsk** on:

```
          JButton no = new JButton("Not yet...");
        no.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        no.setFocusPainted(false);

        no.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    exitAsk.setVisible(false);
                    exitAsk.removeAll();
                    exitAsk.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });
```

**EDIT:** I fixed the "Build path" warning by installing the default workspace library (I did not install it before because... Stupidness). However, it is still asking me to classify the mentioned variables as **final**. Before making *all* those changes to properties, they were never needed. I could run both Action and Mouse Listeners with no problem, now it seems they do not recognize correctly the variables when mentioning them *inside* a Listener.

My question is: As they did not ask that before, do I need to put final on every variable, or is there a way to return back to "normal"?

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of Java? Even 1.7 is ancient.

Comment: What is your question: Why you need to use final, or why you are getting the new error message?

Comment: I made an edit. I am so sorry, not having a clear question was exactly what I was trying to avoid on my first post.

Comment: The concept of effectively final was introduced in Java 8. If you use a Java version below that, you have to state that your variables are final, even if they effectively are.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the old version, too old, try to use a newer JDK

Comment: That sounds strange to me. I was so sure I downloaded the latest version of everything... My JDK is the 14.0.1, and the Eclipse is the newest.

Comment: The external object referenced in the anonymous inner class is restricted by the scope of the external thread and has its specific life cycle. Taking the thread as an example, when the external variable life cycle has ended, the internal thread is still running, how to solve this The external life cycle has ended and needs to be used internally. At this time, you need to add the final modifier to the external variable. In fact, the variable used by the internal anonymous class is a "copy" of the external variable, even if the external variable life cycle Is over.